# How to manually install VS Code Server (without VS Code trying to install again)?

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-code, alpine-linux, vscode-remote

I try to run my Visual Studio code in a container using "Remote-Containers: Reopen in Container". For this I have the following folder structure:

```
.devcontainer/
  devcontainer.env
  devcontainer.json
  Dockerfile
  certs.pem
```

I can build the docker image without problems, but I can still not create the container, as there is a problem downloading and hence installing VS Code Server:

```bsh
Support for Alpine Linux is in preview.

[14250 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
[14252 ms] 
[14252 ms] 
[14252 ms] Exit code 1
[14252 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
[14252 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590499133646
[14254 ms] 
[14254 ms] 
[14254 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[15315 ms] Failed to download VS Code Server (https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/server-linux-alpine/stable): HTTP 407 - authenticationrequired
```

So then I tried to do this manually as suggested here by jia2 and cliffburdick: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/78.

So I added the following lines to my Dockerfile:

```sh
RUN mkdir -p /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590494378070 &&\
cd /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590494378070 && \
curl --proxy "http://<user>:<pw>@<company_domain>:<port>" --cacert /home/certs.pem -L https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/server-linux-alpine/stable -o vscode-server-linux-alpine.tar.gz &&\
tar -xzf vscode-server-linux-alpine.tar.gz
```

Now the problem is that VS Code still tries to make the folder above to install VS Code Server and complains (of course!) that it already exists:

```bsh
[14142 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
[14142 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590496132128
[14144 ms] 
[14144 ms] mkdir: can't create directory '/home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590496132128': Permission denied
[14144 ms] Exit code 1
[14146 ms] Command in container failed: mkdir -p /home/<name>/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0_1590496132128
```

Also according to [SSH with VSCode without internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/ssh-with-vscode-without-internet/56781109#56781109) this should work, but apparently it does not. I am not sure if I could solve it via [Permanently install VS Code's server in container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765127/permanently-install-vs-codes-server-in-container), as I am not really familiar with docker-compose yet.
I would appreciate any suggestions to try-out or pointers to mistakes I made.

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install vscode-server in linux offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline)

Comment: You need to touch `0` in that folder so it knows the installation is done.